# HTML5 video in chrome

Tags: html, html5-video

I'm creating a site that streams video's and I want to allow the user to upload video's themselves. AVI or MP4. I've done some research about it. If I would want to make it cross browser compatible I would have to use all three of these formats:

```
.mp4, .ogv, and .web
```

Luckily I only need to get this to work in chrome. However, it turns out chrome doesnt support .mp4 well. I suppose the best option is to convert them, but I'm not sure. What would be a good solution for this?

Comment: http://www.encoding.com/

Comment: How is the PHP related? Just curious.

Comment: I hope you're not thinking of doing the converting in PHP, right?

Comment: From the w3c http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp mp4 seems fully supported in Chrome.

Comment: @cyrilF Yeah I've seen that link too so I trusted it and tried it out myself. MP4 didnt't work for me and after doing some further research some guy on SO said MP4 wasn't supported.

Comment: Well, I don't see why you need to convert at all. It's not about whether the browser can play the file(s), it's about whether your player can play the files. Flash AS3 can support MP4.

Comment: HTML5 supports it, but not in chrome. I guess I'm going to have to use flash then?

Comment: Lol, you say that like it's a bad thing. Flash is awesome.

Comment: @navnav If you don't care about the millions of people using Android and iOS devices...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I use to play videos on a site I did.:

[Cross Browser Player](http://www.mediaelementjs.com/)

I built all of the uplaod ability with php and use this player to allow user to play the videos.

Comment: I'm going to try that out, mate. It seems like a legit solution :)

Comment: Works really well and is very easy to implement into your site. I use one setup of this player and I pass the file info into it with php.

Comment: Yes you can use this one. It's even recommended by HTML5 please here : http://html5please.com/#video as a recommended polyfill.